# Unable to upload to Amazon S3 via python threads

Tags: python, multithreading

Heres how I thread it.

```
t = Thread(target=s3_upload, args=(absolute_write_path,raw_unique_key))
t.start()
```

Heres the function thats called in threads.

```
def s3_upload(file_path,key):
    conn = S3.AWSAuthConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

    #check if bucket exists, if not cr8 it
    if S3_BUCKET_CHECK:
        if not conn.check_bucket_exists(S3_BUCKET_NAME).status == 200:
            conn.create_located_bucket(S3_BUCKET_NAME, S3_LOCATION)

    orig_file = open(file_path, "r")
    obj = S3Object(orig_file.read())
    conn.put(S3_BUCKET_NAME, key, obj)
    os.remove(file_path)
```

If I don't run it in threads, it seem to work. But if I run in threads, it works up to the line where I do conn.put() and it does not print line from there onwards. Does anyone know why?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not checking return values?

Comment: ok solved it. the problem was that the def daemon value for flask was True. changed it to false (which i assumed was the def) and now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok solved it. the problem was that the def daemon value for flask was True. changed it to false (which i assumed was the def) and now it works :)